# ACF Sort repeater by date

Tags: php, backend, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm using ACF plugin on my site. I want to sort my link containing date. So, in frontend I have something like that

```
01.10.2017, News
02.02.2018, News
06.09.2017, News
```

and I want it to be like that

```
02.02.2018, News
01.10.2017, News
06.09.2017, News
```

My code looks like this

```
<?php

$repeater = get_field('media');
$order = array();

foreach($repeater as $i => $row) {
    $order[$i] = $row['media_date'];
}

array_multisort($order, SORT_ASC, $repeater);

if($repeater): ?>

<ol>
    <?php foreach($repeater as $i => $row): ?>
        <li>
        <?php echo $row['media_date']; ?>, <a href="<?php echo 
$row['media_link']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row['media_title']; ?>
</a>
        </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
<?php else: 
    echo '<p>No matching post!</p>';
endif; ?>
```

And it sort data but incorrect. Incorrect I mean like this

```
01.10.2017, News
02.02.2018, News
06.09.2017, News
```

What I'm missing? How to order li items by date?

Comment: you can convert them to timestamp and than sort them and convert them back to dates

Comment: Thank! I changed my line to $order[$i] = strtotime($row['media_date']); and now it's working